# Как сделать чтоб при обновление сайта текст имел каждый раз разный цвет

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно чтоб при обновление страницы текст в нужном месте менял цвет. Например сверху фотка, а снизу имя и мне нужно чтоб имя менял свой цвет при обновление страницы. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 7):

```
var colors = ["red", "yellow", "green"];
var colorIndex = ((localStorage.getItem("myColorIndex") || -1) + 1) % colors.length;
localStorage.setItem("myColorIndex", colorIndex);
document.getElementById("myId").style.color = colors[colorIndex];
```

Answer (score 6):

Предлагаю через css, особенно если такой элемент не один:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += `
  <style>
     .randomColor {
         color: hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,55%);
      }
  </style>
`;
```

```html
<span class="randomColor"> Hello </span>
```

Или через css-переменную

```js
let color = `hsl(${Math.random()*360},85%,45%)`;
document.body.style.setProperty('--random-color', color);
```

```css
.randomColor {
   color: var(--random-color);
}
```

```html
<span class="randomColor"> Hello </span>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' +
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - 255) + 255) + ',' +
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - 255) + 255) + ',' +
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - 255) + 255) + ')';
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```